# Compute improper integral $\lim_{A\to \infty}\int_{[0,A]} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to compute the improper integral $\displaystyle\lim_{A\to \infty}\int_{[0,A]} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\ \mathrm dx.$

I assumed $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\ \mathrm dt=\frac{1}{x}\; \forall x>0$ (per a hint) and used Fubini and integration by parts to get that the answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to show that $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\ \mathrm dt =\frac{1}{x} \text{ for } x>0$.

Comment: Fundamental theorem and limits

Comment: You mean "$=1/t$" instead of $1/x$. Apply u-substitution.

Comment: Oh, shoot. I actually meant dt not dx.

Comment: This has been asked *so many times* before. Please perform a brief search before asking a new question, especially if about something so classical. $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-tx}\,dt = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ is pretty close to being obvious.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx}\,dt \qquad u=tx\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}\,du\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{x} \left(-e^{-u} \Big |_0^{\infty}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}